# Stop celery workers to consume from all queues

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

Cheers,

I have a celery setup running in a production environment (on Linux) where I need to consume two different task types from two dedicated queues (one for each). The problem that arises is, that all workers are always bound to **both queues**, even when I specify them to only consume from one of them.

### TL;DR

- Celery running with 2 queues
- Messages are published in correct queue as designed
- Workers keep consuming both queues
- Leads to deadlock

### General Information

Think of my two different task types as a hierarchical setup:

- A **task** is a regular celery task that may take quite some time, because it dynamically dispatches other celery tasks and may be required to chain through their respective results
- A **node** is a dynamically dispatched sub-task, which also is a regular celery task but itself can be considered an atomic unit.

My **task** thus can be a more complex setup of **node**s where the results of one or more nodes serves as input for one or more subsequent nodes, and so on. Since my **task**s can take longer and will only finish when all their **node**s have been deployed, it is *essential* that they are handled by dedicated workers to keep a sufficient number of workers free to consume the **node**s. Otherwise, this could lead to the system being stuck, when a lot of **task**s are dispatched, each consumed by another worker, and their respective **node**s are only queued but will never be consumed, because all workers are blocked.

If this is a bad design in general, please make any propositions on how I can improve it. I did not yet manage to build one of these processes using celery's built-in canvas primitives. Help me, if you can?!

### Configuration/Setup

I run celery with `amqp` and have set up the following queues and routes in the celery configuration:

```
CELERY_QUERUES = (
    Queue('prod_nodes', Exchange('prod'), routing_key='prod.node'),
    Queue('prod_tasks', Exchange('prod'), routing_key='prod.task')
)

CELERY_ROUTES = (
    'deploy_node': {'queue': 'prod_nodes', 'routing_key': 'prod.node'},
    'deploy_task': {'queue': 'prod_tasks', 'routing_key': 'prod.task'}
)
```

When I launch my workers, I issue a call similar to the following:

```
celery multi start w_task_01 w_node_01 w_node_02 -A my.deployment.system \
  -E -l INFO -P gevent -Q:1 prod_tasks -Q:2-3 prod_nodes -c 4 --autoreload \
  --logfile=/my/path/to/log/%N.log --pidfile=/my/path/to/pid/%N.pid
```

### The Problem

My queue and routing setup seems to work properly, as I can see messages being correctly queued in the *RabbitMQ Management* web UI.

However, all workers always consume celery tasks from **both** queues. I can see this when I start and open up the *flower* web UI and inspect one of the deployed tasks, where e.g. *w_node_01* starts consuming messages from the *prod_tasks* queue, even though it shouldn't.

The *RabbitMQ Management* web UI furthermore tells me, that all started workers are set up as *consumers* for both queues.

### Thus, I ask you...

... what did I do wrong?

Where is the issue with my setup or worker start call; How can I circumvent the problem of workers always consuming from both queues; Do I really have to make additional settings during runtime (what I certainly do not want)?

Thanks for your time and answers!

Comment: Have you tried not using `multi` and just  create 2 `worker` daemons?

Comment: Not yet, I'll see whether it helps. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 separate workers for each queue and each one's define what queue it should get tasks from using the `-Q` command line argument.

If you want to keep the number processes the same, by default a process is opened for each core for each worker you can use the `--concurrency` flag (See [Celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html) for more info)

Comment: Thanks. `--concurrency` is covered by `-c 4` in my start call, and according to the docs, `-Q` (or `-Q:a-b`) is also issued correctly. However, I'll try to start my workers in two separate calls.

Answer (score 1):

Celery allows configuring a worker with a specific queue.

1) Specify the name of the queue with 'queue' attribute for different types of jobs

```
celery.send_task('job_type1', args=[], kwargs={}, queue='queue_name_1')
celery.send_task('job_type2', args=[], kwargs={}, queue='queue_name_2')
```

2) Add the following entry in configuration file

```
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
```

3) On starting the worker, pass -Q 'queue_name' as argument, for consuming from that desired queue.

```
celery -A proj worker -l info -Q queue_name_1 -n worker1
celery -A proj worker -l info -Q queue_name_2 -n worker2
```